# Best way to map json to a Java object

Tags: java, json, resttemplate

I'm using restTemplate to make a rquest to a servlet that returns a very simple representation of an object in json.

```
{
     "id":"SomeID"
     "name":"SomeName"
}
```

And I have a DTO with those 2 fields and the corresponding setters and getters.
What I would like to know is how to create the object using that json response
without having to "parse" the response.

Comment: How about we edit the title to remove the word "Best" and add "Good" then.

Comment: I apologize for the way I phrased the question. I simply wanted a simple way to map json to an object considering I never had to deal with json before. The answer by Perception was what I had in mind.

Comment: For me, this is top google result for "map json to object java".  The duplicate linked 404s.  Poor show.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I would recommend Jackson. Its fairly lightweight, very fast and requires very little configuration. Here's an example of deserializing:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyBean {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public MyBean() {
        super();
    }

    // Getters/Setters
}


String json = "...";
MyBean bean = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyBean.class);
```

Comment: That `@XmlRootElement` annotation is not necessary for Jackson.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example using [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
public class MyObject {

  private String id;
  private String name;

  // Getters
  public String getId() { return id; }
  public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

And to access it:

```
MyObject obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
System.out.println("ID: " +obj.getId());
System.out.println("Name: " +obj.getName());
```

As far as the *best* way, well that's subjective. This is *one* way you can accomplish what you need.

Comment: How would it be for a list of MyObject? List<MyObject>

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ is nice and lightweight for this

Comment: And how is it "better" than the dozen or so other ones?

Comment: "Better" always depends on what you value. For my part, I am a big fan of the fact that it has no external dependencies, and the first time I found it I was able to get it working very quickly based on their example. I like it because it is what it says it is... simple

Comment: That's the point I was trying to make; the OP's question isn't constructive per SO guidelines. There is no "correct" answer here.

Comment: I think this is also viewable as an update to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668862/good-json-java-library, which is 3 years old. (of course my suggestion also appears there, and perhaps the OP should have searched a bit more first and told us what he found), but I don't think it's unanswerable