# return null for jsonObj.getString("key");

Tags: java, json

```
 JSONObject jsonObj  = {"a":"1","b":null}
```

1. CASE 1 : `jsonObj.getString("a") returns "1";`
2. CASE 2 : `jsonObj.getString("b") return nothing ;`
3. CASE 3 : `jsonObj.getString("c") throws error;`

How to make case 2 and 3 return `null` and not `"null"`?

Comment: "How to make case 2 and 3" you have not given us a case 3

Comment: You've written: "Case 1, 2, 4"

Comment: my bad ! . Thats CASE 3 : In Case  3 , I am trying to get a string which may or may not be present .

Comment: See the the check `has` in my answer.

Comment: if you need empty string, then u can use `jsonObject.optString("key");`

Comment: If an answer solves your issue, please accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `get()` instead of `getString()`. This way an `Object` is returned and JSONObject will guess the right type. Works even for `null`.
Note that there is a difference between Java `null` and `org.json.JSONObject$Null`.

CASE 3 does not return "nothing", it throws an Exception. So you have to check for the key to exist (`has(key)`) and return null instead.

```
public static Object tryToGet(JSONObject jsonObj, String key) {
    if (jsonObj.has(key))
        return jsonObj.opt(key);
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**

As you commented, you only want a `String` or `null`, which leads to `optString(key, default)` for fetching. See the modified code:

```
package test;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Does not work
        // JSONObject jsonObj  = {"a":"1","b":null};

        JSONObject jsonObj  = new JSONObject("{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":null,\"d\":1}");

        printValueAndType(getOrNull(jsonObj, "a")); 
        // >>> 1 -> class java.lang.String

        printValueAndType(getOrNull(jsonObj, "b")); 
        // >>> null -> class org.json.JSONObject$Null

        printValueAndType(getOrNull(jsonObj, "d")); 
        // >>> 1 -> class java.lang.Integer

        printValueAndType(getOrNull(jsonObj, "c")); 
        // >>> null -> null
        // throws org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["c"] not found. without a check
    }

    public static Object getOrNull(JSONObject jsonObj, String key) {
        return jsonObj.optString(key, null);
    }

    public static void printValueAndType(Object obj){
        System.out.println(obj + " -> " + ((obj != null) ? obj.getClass() : null)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: cant test now ! i was thinking of get method as well ..And this  System.out.println(obj + " -> " + ((obj != null) ? obj.getClass() : null)); returns java null or json null since both are different and i would like to retain column As NULL on database instead of string null

Comment: Actually I am in the process of migrating project from request.getparameter ("key") . currently i am using interceptor to parse the form data . seems i need another helper class as well .Will test and mark as accepted

Comment: The print method was just to generate some output and is not very clean, I know. For mapping request params, you can consider using an `ObjectMapper` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068544/best-way-to-map-json-to-a-java-object

Comment: jsonObj.opt(key); didnt solve the problem ; but jsonObj.optString(key) solved it;

Comment: It depends, whether you want want `String` and `null` or `any type` and `null`. I updated the answer and you may accept it or post you own solution.

Answer (score 8):

you can use `optString("c")` or `optString("c", null)`

as stated in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)