# Android app making JSON call gets unexpected data from server, but same call works in browser

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have an Android app that makes a server call which returns JSON.

The server code returns the right string if I enter the URL into a browser. But it creates exceptions in the Java app (different issues with http and https server calls).

```
https://www.problemio.com/auth/mobile_login.php?login=test.name@gmail.com&password=130989
```

Returns this string:

```
[{"user_id":"1601470","email":"test.name@gmail.com","first_name":"TestName","last_name":null}]
```

And this is the Java call that parses the JSON but gives an Exception:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{

    try {
        dialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        // nothing
    }           

    if ( connectionError == true )
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again. Possible Internet connection error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }           

    if ( result != null && result.equals( "no_such_user") )
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your email and password do not match out records. Please try again or create and account.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        //final TextView login_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d( "CONNECTION*** ERRORS: " , "ok 3 and result length: " + result.length()  );

        String firstName = null;
        String lastName = null;
        String email = null;
        String user_id = null;

        try
        {
            JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(0);
            firstName = o.getString("first_name");
            lastName = o.getString("last_name");
            email = o.getString("email");
            user_id = o.getString("user_id");
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Log.d( "JSON ERRORS: " , "something happened ****" + e.getMessage() );
        }


        // 1) First, write to whatever local session file that the person is logged in
        // - I just really need user id and name and email. And store that.
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( 
                LoginActivity.this);

        if ( user_id != null && user_id.trim().length() > 0 && !user_id.trim().equals("null") )
        {
            prefs.edit()
            .putString("first_name", firstName)
            .putString("last_name", lastName)
            .putString("email", email)              
            .putString("user_id", user_id)
            .putBoolean("working", true)
            .commit();

            if ( user_id.equals("1"))
            {
                prefs.edit()
                .putString("community_subscription", "1")
                .commit();
            }
        }
    }
}    
}
```

And this is the exception message:

```
End of input at character 0 of
```

It just looks like the string is 0 characters long.

Any idea why this is happening? Before I switched my site to https this call used to work without problems.

Also the server makes an http call. If I change it to https it returns a whole bunch of HTML which is weird since I don't actually send that back.

This is my doInBackground method:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
{
    String myUrl = theParams[0];
    final String myEmail = theParams[1];
    final String myPassword = theParams[2];

    String charset = "UTF-8";           

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
    {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication( myEmail, myPassword.toCharArray());
        }
    });
```

### Edit

If my doInBackground method is inside the

```
public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

Can it be that the server is just too slow to return the string and that is why it is getting null?

It is always crashing on this with the result string being empty:

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);
```

### Edit 2

Here is the full code:

```
package com.problemio;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;

import utils.SendEmail;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity 
{
    //private TextView textView;
    private Dialog dialog;

    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "8CA5LTZ5M73EG8R35SXG");

        setContentView(R.layout.login);        

        //final TextView emailask = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_ask);

        // Show form for login_email
        final EditText loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);  
        //String name = loginEmail.getText().toString();

        // Show field for password  
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        //String text = password.getText().toString();
        //Log.d( "First parameters: " , "Login email: " + loginEmail + " AND login password: " +  text);


        // Show button for submit
        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);   

        submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
              String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
              String pass = password.getText().toString();

               //Set the email pattern string
//            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
//            //Match the given string with the pattern
//            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(email);
//            //check whether match is found
//            boolean matchFound = m.matches();               

              // TODO: VALIDATE!!!
              if ( email == null || email.trim().length() < 2 )
              {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                       
              }
              else
              if ( pass == null || pass.trim().length() < 2 )
              {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a correct password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
              }
              else
              {
                 sendFeedback(pass, email); 
              }  
           }
        });        

        // Show button for submit
        Button forgot_password = (Button)findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);   

        forgot_password.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

              Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
              LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);           
           }
        });                

        // Now add messaging for creating a profile
        final TextView create_profile_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create_profile_message);

        Button create_profile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_profile);   

        create_profile.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
                //sendEmail("Create Profile Clicked", "From Login screen, someone clicked on the create profile button" );   

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CreateProfileActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
           }
        });        

    }

    public void sendFeedback(String pass , String email) 
    {  
        String[] params = new String[] { "http://www.problemio.com/auth/mobile_login.php", email, pass };

        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(params);        
    }          

    // Subject , body
    public void sendEmail( String subject , String body )
    {
        String[] params = new String[] { "http://www.problemio.com/problems/send_email_mobile.php", subject, body };

        SendEmail task = new SendEmail();
        task.execute(params);               
    }

    public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
         private boolean connectionError = false;

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute( ) 
         {
              dialog = new Dialog(LoginActivity.this);

              dialog.setContentView(R.layout.please_wait);
                dialog.setTitle("Logging You In");

              TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.please_wait_text);
                text.setText("Please wait while you are being logged in...");
              dialog.show();
         }

         // orig
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... theParams)
        {
            String myUrl = theParams[0];
            final String myEmail = theParams[1];
            final String myPassword = theParams[2];

            String charset = "UTF-8";

            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
            {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication( myEmail, myPassword.toCharArray());
                }
            });

            String response = null;

            String stringUrl = "https://www.problemio.com/auth/mobile_login.php?login=test.name@gmail.com&password=130989";
            String result = "";
            String inputLine;

            try
            {
                String query = String.format("login=%s&password=%s",
                         URLEncoder.encode(myEmail, charset),
                         URLEncoder.encode(myPassword, charset));

                final URL url = new URL( myUrl + "?" + query );

                final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("login", myEmail);
                conn.setRequestProperty("password", myPassword);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setUseCaches(false);

                conn.connect();

                final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
                int readCount;
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1)
                {
                    builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
                }

                response = builder.toString();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                  sendEmail ( "Login Activity 1 Network Error" , "Error: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            return response;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                // nothing
            }           

            if ( connectionError == true )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again. Possible Internet connection error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }           

            if ( result != null && result.equals( "no_such_user") )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your email and password do not match out records. Please try again or create and account.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                //final TextView login_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
            }
            else
            {

                String firstName = null;
                String lastName = null;
                String email = null;
                String user_id = null;

                try
                {
                    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);
                    Log.d( "CONNECTION*** ERRORS: " , ".....5"  );
                    JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(0);
                    firstName = o.getString("first_name");
                    lastName = o.getString("last_name");
                    email = o.getString("email");
                    user_id = o.getString("user_id");

                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    Log.d( "JSON ERRORS: " , "some crap happened ****" + e.getMessage() );
                }


                // 1) First, write to whatever local session file that the person is logged in
                // - I just really need user id and name and email. And store that.
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( 
                        LoginActivity.this);

                if ( user_id != null && user_id.trim().length() > 0 && !user_id.trim().equals("null") )
                {
                    prefs.edit()
                    .putString("first_name", firstName)
                    .putString("last_name", lastName)
                    .putString("email", email)              
                    .putString("user_id", user_id)
                    .putBoolean("working", true)
                    .commit();

                    if ( user_id.equals("1"))
                    {
                        prefs.edit()
                        .putString("community_subscription", "1")
                        .commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    // TODO: see if I can get rid of this
    public void readWebpage(View view) 
    {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.problemio.com/auth/mobile_login.php" });
    }       

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
       super.onStop();
    }       
}
```

Comment: The HTML returned might contain the error you're looking for. Anyhow it's meaningful, even if you don't send it yourself. Additionally you need to add the full `doInBackground`. The most important parts are missing.

Comment: How do you call the service? Are you using `HttpURLConnection` or what?

Comment: First of all don't use AsyncTask because it's old technology if you use retrofit and Rx Java this type of issue not happen, if you want to migrate i will provide you sample with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**ISSUE #1**

From your question description:

> The server code returns the right string if I enter the URL into a
>   browser.

I'm assuming you are using **HTTP GET**. However you are using **HTTP POST** in your code instead:

```
String query = String.format("login=%s&password=%s",
                         URLEncoder.encode(myEmail, charset),
                         URLEncoder.encode(myPassword, charset));

                final URL url = new URL( myUrl + "?" + query );

                final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); // <----------- replace with "GET"
```

**ISSUE #2**

```
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

When set to true the request method is changed to **POST**, since **GET** or **DELETE** can't have a request body. To continue with a **GET** request you must set `conn.setDoOutput(false);`

Also, comment out those lines:

```
//conn.setRequestProperty("login", myEmail);
//conn.setRequestProperty("password", myPassword);
//conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

**ISSUE #3**

```
 task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.problemio.com/auth/mobile_login.php" });
```

> From Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted

You must change the URL from **http** to **https** or add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the manifest. This will only effect on devices running API level 23+. Before 23+ **http** is allowed by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For me using **https** worked properly.

**ISSUE #4**

Upon providing wrong credentials your server is sending a plain text message

> no_such_user

Which needs to be replaced with a valid JSON string.

From my end, the code you provided is working properly after fixing those issues.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. One question - now I have this in the manifest:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" /> - was this the right way to add that attribute? It . is in the uses-permission? Also it says this works for API level 23 and above - will this still break for phones that use API level below that?

Comment: Check the updated answer. This should clear your confusions.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code using HttpURLConnection in async task, It gave me the desired output without error..  But if I give different password in the get url.. the response is not JSONObject. It is coming as String value. may be that causing the issue(u handle that also in postexecute method)

```
public class HttpGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String stringUrl = "https://www.problemio.com/auth/mobile_login.php?login=test.name@gmail.com&password=130989";
        String result = "";
        String inputLine;
        try {
            //Create a URL object holding our url
            URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);
            //Create a connection
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
                    myUrl.openConnection();
            //Set methods and timeouts
            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            //Connect to our url
            connection.connect();
            //Create a new InputStreamReader
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new
                    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            //Create a new buffered reader and String Builder
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //Check if the line we are reading is not null
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }
            //Close our InputStream and Buffered reader
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();
            //Set our result equal to our stringBuilder
            result = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       // textView.setText("Response is: " + response);
        try {
            JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(0);
            String firstName = o.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = o.getString("last_name");
            String email = o.getString("email");
            String user_id = o.getString("user_id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not too sure how your solution would fit my case since I don't use Volley.

Comment: can u share your doInBackground method also?

Comment: edited my answer - replaced volley with asyncTask.. Your code seems correct only. and try to print your URL before using it. It may be wrong

Comment: I just added it to the original question. Thank you!

Comment: I think your are returning empty string at the end of doInBackground method. I also getting the same error if I return empty string without calling the HttpUrlConnection codings

Comment: What would be the right solution in this situation?

Comment: This also crashes for me on JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);

Comment: The String result seems to be always empty when processed by the code. Is it a possible http/https issue or something else?

Comment: I think you are not calling the API actually,, did you use the above code in doInBackground.

Comment: I tried that code and it had the same problem where the server returned an empty string - do you think it could be an issue with https vs http server calls? My server got switched to https and some of these calls stopped working correctly when calling them from the app.

Comment: I don't think its because of https. You didn't shared doInBackground method fully.. need to know what is returning in that method

Answer (score 1):

Looking your Json I can see a null

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "1601470",
    "email": "test.name@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "TestName",
    "last_name": null
  }
]
```

Json files accept nulls, but json objects do not accept it.

The application is crashing when you try to get the `last_name`.

Instead of null use empty.

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "1601470",
    "email": "test.name@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "TestName",
    "last_name": ""
  }
]
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you! Is the solution to just return " " in case of an empty field for last name? Or is it better to handle that in the Java code?

Comment: You are welcome!, is the solution because right now I think its a bug, because is unhandleable. You have methods with JSONObject to check if is ISNULL but dont work.
At least for me.

Comment: Do you mean that o.getString("last_name"); will always crash if last name is empty? Or is there a good way to check for it? What would be the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778623/return-null-for-jsonobj-getstringkey/41778906

Comment: Why did you separate it into its own method? For aesthetics or some practical reason?

Comment: I tried to implement what you did, but I don't really understand what is happening there. Why are you returning an Object? What do I do with it later?

Comment: I edited it again. Look the awnser of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778623/return-null-for-jsonobj-getstringkey/41778906

Answer (score 1):

As per google this is old technique Retrieve API data using AsyncTask, I prefer Retrofit + RxJava + RxAndroid + GSON.

It will remove all your boilerplate code. It is so easy to use Retrofit.

Add Below dependency in your app,

```
//retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
//Rx android
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'
```

Create MyRetrofit class,

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MyRetrofit {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        String BASE_URL = "https://www.problemio.com/";
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            httpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

                httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
            }
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();

        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Create APIService Class,

```
    import in.kintanpatel.customrecylerview.model.LoginBean;
    import io.reactivex.Observable;
    import retrofit2.Response;
    import retrofit2.http.GET;
    import retrofit2.http.Query;

    /**
     * Created by kintan on 8/11/18.
     */

    public interface APIService {
//Add All your method here

        @GET("auth/mobile_login.php/")
        Observable<Response<ArrayList<LoginBean>>> doLogin(@Query("login") String login, @Query("password") String password);

    }
```

That's it now call your API stuff here,

```
private void doLoginAPI(String userName, String password) {
        //Show Loading here
        MyRetrofit.getInstance().create(APIService.class).doLogin(userName, password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Response<ArrayList<LoginBean>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response<ArrayList<LoginBean>> response) {
                        //Hide Loading here
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) { //check HTTP Response
                            LoginBean bean = response.body().get(0);
                            Log.e("USER_INFO", "User ID: " + bean.getUserId());
                            Log.e("USER_INFO", "User First Name : " + bean.getFirstName());
                            Log.e("USER_INFO", "User Last Name : " + bean.getLastName());
                            Log.e("USER_INFO", "User Email : " + bean.getEmail());

                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("USER_INFO", e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });

    }
```

And just call your method where you want:

```
 doLoginAPI("test.name@gmail.com", "130989");
```

And Your output like,

```
11-08 14:44:59.946 25447-25447/com.kintanpatel.baserecyclerview E/USER_INFO: User ID: 1601470
11-08 14:44:59.946 25447-25447/com.kintanpatel.baserecyclerview E/USER_INFO: User First Name : TestName
11-08 14:44:59.946 25447-25447/com.kintanpatel.baserecyclerview E/USER_INFO: User Last Name : null
11-08 14:44:59.946 25447-25447/com.kintanpatel.baserecyclerview E/USER_INFO: User Email : test.name@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thank you! Would the MyRetrofit class be instead of the Activity?Now I have things in an Activity class like this: public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity - would I have to guy it all entirely to implement your solution?

Comment: I also just pasted my whole Activity into the question so it is easier to reference parts of it.