# How to convert String to Generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class similar to this:

```
public class Car<T> {
   private T model;
   private CarBodyParts body;
}
```

```
public class CarBodyParts {
   private Integer carWidth;
   private Integer carHeight;
}
```

```
public class Jaguar {
   private String name;
   private Integer wheelsCount;
}
```

String val = "{ "model": { "name": "Jaguar", "wheelsCount": 4 }, "body": { "carWidth": 100, "carHeight": 20 } }"

How can I convert this string val to  `Car<Jaguar>` object?

Comment: Generics are compile-time type safety, you're talking about parsing some value at runtime. Best you can do is check the properties then cast it. Also, I forgot Jaguars are the only cars with wheels :)

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068544/best-way-to-map-json-to-a-java-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.2.2) library to convert the string to class.
Add the below dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Use the below code to convert the string to Car:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String str = "{ \"model\": { \"name\": \"Jaguar\", \"wheelsCount\": 4 }, \"body\": { \"carWidth\": 100, \"carHeight\": 20 } }";
Car<Jaguar> car1 = objectMapper.readValue(str,Car.class);
```

Read more on jackson from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)